# Android onBackPressed avoid exit

Tags: android, back-stack, onbackpressed

When the user press the back button on his device I want to move to the previous `Activity` but not to go back to the `Home.`

For example, if the user has opened some `Activities`, the back stack is supposed to be:

- Activity_A
- Activity_B
- Activity_C [ Currently displayed ]

When the user presses the `Back button`, it's supposed to get:

- Activity_A
- Activity_B [ Currently displayed ]

And the, if he presses the button once again:

- Activity_A [ Currently displayed ]

**Then I want to disable this button to avoid to go back to the `Home screen`.**

Is that possible ?

So far, I'm using this method, but I've read that it won't be supported on `Android L`:

```
protected int getActivitiesStackSize()
{
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    return taskList.get(0).numActivities; 
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // Pop activity
    if (getActivitiesStackSize() != 1) super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**Activity_A may be any `Activity` in my project.**

Comment: Try to override OnBackPressed in Activity_A and make it empty

Comment: Activity_A may be any `Activity` in my project. Sorry, I forgot to say it.

Comment: Keep in mind that you might alienate users if you simply disable the back button. At the very least, provide a toast or a "double-tap to exit" functionality as explained elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override the back button event and then move between activities except on activity A where the back button should still exit. example

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

        //Move to previous activity

        return true;
    }

    // If it wasn't the Back key, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Activity_A may be any `Activity` in my project. Sorry, I forgot to say it.

Comment: So the app can start at any activity and move forward to other activities and you want to exit once the starting activity is reached if the back button is pressed?

Comment: Yes, exactly ! You've undertsood my problem. Basically, all previous activities have been `finished`.

Comment: How about creating a static variable where you add activity names once you open them. Then as the back button is pressed you move down through the list until the list is empty?

Comment: In which methods am I supposed to `push` and `pop` ? I'm aware that if the `Activity` is getting killed by the system, the `onDestroy` method might not be called.

Comment: is it possible to recreate the activities as you move backwards or is it important to keep the state of the activities?

Comment: It is important to keep the state.

Comment: I think isTaskRoot would then basically be the only option but google screwed a lot of developers by deprecating getRunningTasks so at least misery has company. Have you though about making the app web based and then using the webview history?

Comment: This would effectively be an option. Thanks for your precious help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //Handle the back button
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && isTaskRoot()) {
        //Ask the user if they want to quit
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setTitle(R.string.quit)
        .setMessage(R.string.really_quit)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Stop the activity
                finish();    
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
        .show();

        return true;
    }
    else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. `isTaskRoot` would probably work but  that's not exactly what I'm looking for. Is there a way to manually get a `activities stack size` counter even when the `Activity` is killed (Not getting `onDestroy` called) ?

Answer (score -1):

Use android:noHistory="true" in manifest for activity you want not to get navigated to. No history will not let the activity to get stored in stack. On pressing back in Activity_B application will be closed. If this is what you want you can use this feature.

Comment: Activity_A may be any `Activity` in my project. Sorry, I forgot to say it.